# make data all data return in one row

Tags: sql, row, coalesce

I have a table and my data look like this:

```
ID      name        contact
1234    company XYZ jane@xyz.com
1234    company XYZ john@xyz.com
1234    company XYZ sue@xyz.com
1234    company XYZ mark@xyz.com
1234    company XYZ jack@xyz.com
1234    company XYZ alex@xyz.com
```

But I need this result set:

```
ID      name         contact
12345   company XYZ  jane@xyz.com,john@xyz.com,sue@xyz.com,mark@xyz.com,jack@xyz.com,alex@xyz.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example:

```
SELECT  ID, Name,
        STUFF((SELECT ',' + Contact
               FROM SomeTable 
               WHERE ID = t.ID
               FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') Contacts
FROM SomeTable t
GROUP BY ID, Name
```